# Executing nested WaterfallDialogs - nodejs

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm trying to build a requirement system for order dialogs in our bot, so that we can reuse the main structure for different procedures.

```
enum DialogIds {
    // Necessary Ids
    oauthPrompt = "oauthPrompt",

    // Requirement dialogs
    itemWaterfallDialog = "itemWaterfallDialog",

    // Reset Dialogs
    summaryWaterfallDialog = "summaryWaterfallDialog",

    // All other prompts
    unrecognizedItemPrompt = "unrecognizedItemPrompt",
    beneficiaryConfirmPrompt = "beneficiaryConfirmPrompt",
    askBeneficiaryPrompt = "askBeneficiaryPrompt",
    reasonPrompt = "reasonPrompt",
    orderConfirm = "orderConfirm"
}

export class OrderDialog extends ComponentDialog {
    private responseManager: ResponseManager;
    private requirementManager: RequirementManager;
    private luisResult: RecognizerResult | undefined = undefined;

    // TODO: get userState and ConversationState
    constructor(
        private service: BotServices,
        telemetryClient: BotTelemetryClient
    ) {
        super(OrderDialog.name);

        this.initialDialogId = OrderDialog.name;

        // Response manager serving OrderResponses.json
        this.responseManager = new ResponseManager(["fr-fr"], [OrderResponses]);

        const routeWaterfallDialog: ((
            sc: WaterfallStepContext
        ) => Promise<DialogTurnResult>)[] = [
            this.route.bind(this)
        ];

        this.telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
        this.addDialog(
            new WaterfallDialog(this.initialDialogId, routeWaterfallDialog)
        );

        /**
         * Order specific dialogs and requirements
         */

        const itemWaterfallDialog: WaterfallDialog = new WaterfallDialog(
            DialogIds.itemWaterfallDialog,
            [this.itemStep.bind(this), this.itemEndStep.bind(this)]
        );
        this.addDialog(itemWaterfallDialog);

        const reqs = [
            new Requirement<string>("claimant", false, undefined),
            new Requirement<string>(
                "item",
                true,
                undefined,
                itemWaterfallDialog,
                DialogIds.itemWaterfallDialog
            ),
        ];

        // Create requirement manager for this dialog
        this.requirementManager = new RequirementManager(reqs);

        // Add all the prompt
        this.addDialog(new ConfirmPrompt(DialogIds.beneficiaryConfirmPrompt));
        this.addDialog(new TextPrompt(DialogIds.unrecognizedItemPrompt));
        this.addDialog(new TextPrompt(DialogIds.askBeneficiaryPrompt));
        this.addDialog(new TextPrompt(DialogIds.reasonPrompt));
        this.addDialog(new ConfirmPrompt(DialogIds.orderConfirm));
    }

    /**
     * We save the token, query graph is necessary and
     * execute the next dialog if any, if not we'll
     * execute the summary waterfallDialog.
     * @param sc context
     */
    async route(sc: WaterfallStepContext): Promise<DialogTurnResult> {
        this.requirementManager.set("claimant", 'nothing');

        let next = this.requirementManager.getNext();
        while (next) {

            await sc.beginDialog(next.dialogId!);

            // Execute summary if there are no elements left
            if (!this.requirementManager.getNextBool()) {
                await sc.beginDialog(DialogIds.summaryWaterfallDialog);
            }
            next = this.requirementManager.getNext();
        }

        return sc.endDialog();
    }

    /**
     * ITEM
     * @param sc
     */

    async itemStep(sc: WaterfallStepContext): Promise<DialogTurnResult> {
        // Couldn't recgonize any item
        if (this.luisResult!.entities.length === 0) {
            await sc.context.sendActivity(
                this.responseManager.getResponse(
                    OrderResponses.itemNotRecognized
                )
            );

            // prompt user for the item again
            return await sc.prompt(
                DialogIds.unrecognizedItemPrompt,
                this.responseManager.getResponse(OrderResponses.rePromptItem)
            );
        }

        const entities = this.luisResult!.entities as generalLuis["entities"];

        if (entities.PhoneItem || entities.ComputerItem) {
            const item = entities.PhoneItem
                ? entities.PhoneItem
                : entities.ComputerItem;

            if (item) {
                this.requirementManager.set("item", item[0][0]);
            }
        }

        return await sc.next();
    }

    async itemEndStep(sc: WaterfallStepContext): Promise<DialogTurnResult> {
        // Save result from itemStep(prompt triggered) if any
        if (sc.result) {
            await sc.context.sendActivity(
                this.responseManager.getResponse(OrderResponses.thanksUser)
            );

            // retrieve item from result and save it
            const item = sc.result as string;
            this.requirementManager.set("item", item);
        }

        return sc.endDialog();
    }

}
```

The line

```
const result = await sc.beginDialog(next.dialogId!);
```

Is starting a WaterfallDialog declared in the constructor of the Dialog, and the route method is also inside a general waterfallDialog.

The problem is that, when one of the child dialogs prompts the user, the code doesn't wait for the user response, and because of the way the route works it will call the same dialog again(if a value on an object is not filled it will call the indicated dialog, that's what the requirement manager does).

If saving the return from that line, we can see that the status is "waiting", how could I fix it, or should I create independent dialogs for each requirement, and not just waterfallDialogs?

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like something is wrong with your routing or you're not saving state between steps. Are you able to link to your full code? This can be very difficult to troubleshoot without it and is very easy to fix with it. At the very least, could you update the questions with the code from one of the dialogs that is not working as well as the code related to you saving state (something like `conversationState.saveChanges()`?

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT I've updated the code with most of the dialog, the state is being saved by the AutoSaveStateMiddleware in the adapter. If you are not able to find the mistake, but could have any idea on how we could implement a reusable requirement system that will also be enough. Thanks

Comment: Can you expand on "The problem is that, when one of the child dialogs prompts the user, the code doesn't wait for the user response, and because of the way the route works it will call the same dialog again(if a value on an object is not filled it will call the indicated dialog, that's what the requirement manager does)."? One issue I see is that in `itemStep`, it doesn't appear that `luisResult` or `entities` will *ever* be anything other than `undefined`.

Comment: I ran into this issue before but I can't remember exactly what my situation was. You are running into this issue because the code is awaiting the START of the dialog, not the completion of it. I believe I fixed mine by having the beginDialog() statement as part of the return for the waterfall step. But the way you are looping your begin dialog statement, I'm not sure how you would do that.

Comment: I'm getting something to work replacing the onContinueDialog() behaviour, the problem was exactly as you said @billoverton. Now I simply continue the child dialog if there is one, else I check for the next requirement (I did add the waterfall dialogs into different files though).